# Is it possible to use environment variables in prettier config?

Tags: config, prettier

I have this config

```
plugins:
  - "${HOME}/.local/share/nvm/v18.12.1/lib/node_modules/prettier-plugin-sql"
```

and am trying to use this prettier config to load a plugin, but I keep getting an error:

```
[error] Cannot find module '${HOME}/.local/share/nvm/v18.12.1/lib/node_modules/prettier-plugin-sql'
[error] Require stack:
[error] - /home/user/.npm/_npx/b388654678d519d9/node_modules/prettier/index.js
[error] - /home/user/.npm/_npx/b388654678d519d9/node_modules/prettier/cli.js
[error] - /home/user/.npm/_npx/b388654678d519d9/node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js
```

Is is possible to expand the env variable somehow?
I need my prettier config to be .yaml or .json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use environment variables in YAML or JSON configuration files directly.
You have two main options:

1. Create a JavaScript configuration file (e.g., prettier.config.js) to use environment variables.
2. Write a script that generates a JSON configuration file using environment variables. This generated file will need to be updated or recreated for new deployments, depending on the changes in environment variables.